# Google Calendar Link Generator - Repeat event

Tags: url, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm finding a webtool to generate a Google Calendar link event with a repeat parameters. For example I would like to create an event with this data:

Title: Example event
Location: Office
Description: This is a description of an example event.
Start Date: 01/10/2021
Start Time: 10:00:00h
**Repeat at:** each months.

I have found URL as like:

https://jennamolby.com/google-calendar-link-generator/

But in this URL I cann't to set a repeat parameter.

An URL example without repeat time event parameter is this:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20211001T100000Z%2FT010000Z&text=Example%20event&location=Office&details=This%20is%20a%20description%20of%20an%20example%20event.%20
```

I would like to find documentation about all possible parameters to create Google Calendar events.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at using the Calendar API? https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/overview

Answer (score 5):

The parameter to insert a repeat event is:

```
&recur=RRULE:FREQ%3DMONTHLY&sf=true
```

In this example the repeat is monthly.